# How can I use jQuery in an Office Add-in after npm install?

Tags: jquery, ajax, word-addins

Started an Office add-in project as per the documentation using Yeoman Generator. I'd like to make calls to an outside ASP.NET Web Service using jQuery's Ajax function.

Did `npm install jQuery` to get the latest version and have it being copied to a static/jQuery folder but I don't know how to reference it in my project to use in my command.js file.

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question, but why do you need to introduce the overhead of jQuery just to make HTTP calls to a web service? Why not any of the other built in Node functions (`fetch`, `http`, etc.)? In any case: what have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Are you seeing any errors? Have you tried `require()`-ing jQuery?

Comment: you can refer the path of jquery in your script using the node_modules folder as a reference.